# A perfect filter spell. What knowledge could it bring?

Tags: magic, scientific-development

I am only asking about knowledge. What things can be **learned** more easily now that this item can be used. I know that it could result in a faster scientific advancement due to it creating an abundance in resources.

In my magic system one can enchant a physical frame with a spell that would create a barrier that only lets a named object or substance pass. The frame can be of all shapes and sizes but has to exist in a single plane (mathematical plane). The magic is smart enough that it can work with basically any named physical substance. But it does not differentiate about the state of the substance. Allowing water through would also let water vapour through. There are easier ways of creating power in my world so it wouldn't be likely that this was used to create power. It can't do chemistry and all of the natural forces work through the barrier.

> Or sodium from chloride and make a battery recombining the two.

this wouldn't work that well because the salt would stay together.

The mage in the story has invented the spell as an security system. He specified himself to be the only one able to go through the barrier (with clothes). But one of the side characters has the same name and was able to snoop around in the private quarters. Later on they used it to make a clean (demineralised water) bath from sewage water and a device that can check the purity of molten coins.

The scientific knowledge in my world is roughly equivalent to the early middle ages. With this spell they would quickly find lots of pure elements and substances. And then be able to slowly build the periodic table of elements. What other scientific knowledge would be **easily** figured out when this spell spreads through the mages society?

*easily: to constrain the answer. Assume a couple of years with a small group of people. Anything invented/found after the 10th century is not known at the start.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130159/discussion-on-question-by-postlim-fort-a-perfect-filter-spell-what-knowledge-co).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Germ Theory.**

In the middle ages people didn't know that illness is caused by micro-organisms. They believed other strange things like miasma theory, that illness is spread by bad smells.

Your filter could be used to discover there is some bad substance in dirty water. For example you can filter out all  all known substances, like soil, plants, insects, and get some concentrated microorganism slurry. You don't need to know exactly what is in the slurry.

Then put that on a piece of bread and observe it goes rancid super quickly. Feed the bread to a pig and the pig becomes sick. But mix some alcohol with the slurry and it prevents the bread going rancid. Run the pig through the filter and it miraculously becomes well again.

Finally give the slurry a name. Then you can filter it out of other foods to prevent them going rotten.

Comment: "Run the pig through the filter and it miraculously becomes well again." that will be an interesting sight. suddenly being torn full of holes from all of the germs being forced through that bone, flesh and skin. lets hope that none get stuck in the skull?

Comment: @PostlimFort why doesn't it happen to the original mage, the one that invented the spell? I mean, his guts are full of bacteria already, they aren't part "the mage and his cloths", and the filter - as limited to just filtering it may be - is a ["literal genie"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LiteralGenie) - it separated pure water from the sewage, even if the request didn't explicitly asked for it.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi good point. the original mage allowed anything carried with him through the filter. (originaly for home decoration purposes). i suspect that in making someone healthy. one would need to specify that the germs are not allowed through.

Answer (score 2):

Opening: *"The magic is smart enough that it can work with basically any named physical substance."* (...) *"The scientific knowledge in my world is roughly equivalent to the early middle ages. With this spell they would quickly find lots of pure elements and substances. And then be able to slowly build the periodic table of elements.*

**Unknown substances have no name**

The only actual knowledge is initially with the Mages. They know the names of substances, needed to invoke specific filter spells. But to yield scientific knowledge comparible to a periodic table, it will not suffice to just assign names. Unknown substances will not have names. Known substances will have all kinds of names, like "salt" which actually represents a chemical compound consisting of two elements, Sodium (isolated 1807) and  Chlorine (isolated 1774)

**To derive knowledge, require proton count rather than assigned names**

There are just over hundred elements. It would help for the Magus' exploration process, if the Magus could specify the number of protons during invocation of the spell. The Mage has a big book, containing all kinds of chemical  substances related to these numbers. When the filter spell is invoked, one or more numbers are chanted, as part of the magic invocation rite. When this magic exists for a while, Mages could eventually grasp the periodic table system and might even find how elctron energy levels and chemical bounds are related to these numbers. Realizing water consists of hydrogen and oxigen took until 1766 to find out. But with proton count  filter spells, the knowledge could have been developed much earlier.

*What other scientific knowledge would be easily figured out when this spell spreads through the mages society?"*

**Early industrial revolution ? Early flight ?**

These filter spells would come in handy for industrial development.  Processes can be controlled in a way we cannot normally do, if you have some immaterial 2d wall for instant separation of substances. When copper and iron can be instantly separated from the ore, by throwing the ore through the filter, yielding metal, it could help development of technology ! Another option I can think of: harvesting hydrogen from water. That would be an interesting energy source.. and when contained, an opportunity to fly balloons in medieval times. When the filter spells are refined, one could think of extracting medicine from plants, helping to develop medical knowledge.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine how they would stumble upon the idea of proton count with such limited technology. Unless of course they got the idea from the filter in the first place?

Comment: Well because magic like a "filter spell" could originate from earlier civilizations, or aliens ? For the medieval Mage, the list with substances and "magic" numbers it is just a reference cookbook. But after a few hundred years, the Mages may realize there is knowledge underneath these numbers. The only reason for proposing numbers instead of names, is knowledge may never expand when names are required for all spells. When numbers are used, the Mage can experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Being the "universal solvent" many compounds could be extracted from seawater, freshwater or best yet, raw sewage.

Many/most metals such as gold, exist in vast quantities dissolved in water waiting to be extracted by a series of cascading screens. Each fishing out a rare mineral. In fact, the final screen could filter for pure water.

Screens could likely be constantly fed by tidal action or in the case of a freshwater river or sewage natural gravity making this all mostly automatic.

For context, it is estimated that the Swiss flush down the toilet 2 million euros of dissolved gold a year. Sea water is estimated to contain 5 million pounds of gold per cubic mile of water. Fresh water potentially averages 1000 times that concentration.

Sure that is a lot of water but with free motion of the tides or a river it would not take that long to pass large quantities of water through the system.

Comment: thanks, but the question is about what knowledge can be gained?

Comment: Well for one thing, the knowledge that water was the universal solvent and that almost any metal can be extracted from it. A person placing a screen in a river and idly and on a whim stating gold as the material to be filtered for would likely be shocked to return the next day and find actual gold accumulating. Then silver, platinum, copper, iron...